# GridView: Retrieve value of TemplateField in RowDeleting event

Tags: asp.net

My gridview is bound to List when users click a refresh button as follows:

```
grv_xyz.DataSource = lstVendorInfo;
grv_zyz.DataBind();
```

I put a `<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />` before all other TemplateFields to display data like

```
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor ID">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" BorderColor="#efefef" BorderWidth="1px"/>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="#" ID="abcID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("abc") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#efefef" />
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

The problem is cell. Text property in the following is `""`.

```
protected void grv_Vendor_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    ShowResult();
    TableCell cell = grv_Vendor.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4];
}
```

How could I retieve the value inside a TemplateField in RowDeleting event?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TemplateField includes controls, so the value should be accessed through them. For example, if you have a label inside a TemplateField and you want to access its value, you would write:

```
Label yourLabel = e.Item.FindControl("YourLabelID") as Label;
string val = yourLabel.Text;
```